# How can I copy link to clipboard, to use it in wysiwyg editor (JS, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, copy, clipboard

I have list of hyperlinks on my website. I need to do this:

- User clicks on the link, it goes to his clipboard
- User goes to another website and pastes the text in wysiwyg, or any other editor
- Data needs to be pasted not as HTML, but like a link.

For example, i can do the same just when I select any hyperlink on any website and paste it in any editor. How can I do it via JS, jQuery?

Answer (score -1):

There is the following function - you can read more about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

There is also a library for this:
http://steamdev.com/zclip/

Note the examples in action:
http://steamdev.com/zclip/#notes

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is....

```js
window.prompt("Header", "text");
```